# Intellij Idea lib folder export

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, apk, libgdx

I am using `IntelliJ Idea`  for the java `libgdx` development. I have 3 android/desktop modules which  shares the same `libgdx` libraries. Currently i put libgdx libs in all 3 android/desktop modules. But its going to be more than 10 modules. And its a pain process.

So what i did is,  created a common android/desktop lib folder in a a root level and added that folder as a lib dependency in each android/desktop module. Desktop compiles and runs fine. But Android app compiles but not running. I am getting this error

> "caused by com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException couldn't load
>   shared library 'gdx' for target: Linux, 32-bit"

I opened generated `apk`, it doesnt have the libgdx jar files. Even I tried setting export option for android libs in module settings. But its not working. Check the screenshot

[image]

I wanted the idea to export the linked referenced libraries to apk bundle. is there a way?

Comment: have you copied the `gdx.jar` into the `libs` folder of your android project? And don't forget the native libraries folder `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a`.

Comment: watch this it might help you   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pj4wFmAcgVc

Comment: @VikalpJain, thanks man. libgdx project is working fine by traditional  configuration. here i want to move lib folders out of each android module to root to have them used in multiple modules. any ideas?

Comment: @RameshVel  check this if this works for you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698358/gdxruntimeexception-on-android-couldnt-load-shared-library-gdx-for-target

Comment: I haven't tried intellij idea but i think you have set up all the libraries for android and desktop under same project. make them seperate for android and desktop and then try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is by default android modulle looks for the reference libraries under the lib folder of the particular module itself. I resolved this by changing Native libs directory from the module lib to the root lib. It works fine now. Attached the screenshot for reference

[image]