# app crashes on start using libgdx

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, libgdx

my game crashes on my Lenovo IdeaTab A2109 running android 4.1.1(it seemed to work previously), but it works fine on my galaxy s2 running android 4.1.2.
My minSDK in Manifest file: 14 and target: 18.
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4. I checked the export thing in my android module, didn't solve my problem.

```
    09-20 13:22:14.269: WARN/dalvikvm(11166): Exception Lcom/badlogic/gdx/utils/GdxRuntimeException; thrown while initializing Lcom/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplication;

    09-20 13:22:14.269: WARN/dalvikvm(11166): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/comraz/slashem/MainActivity;)

    09-20 13:22:14.269: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(11166): Shutting down VM

    09-20 13:22:14.269: WARN/dalvikvm(11166): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x411102a0)

    09-20 13:22:14.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11166): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)

    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)

    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)

    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)

    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
```

Edit:

I created an eclipse project and added all my classes there and it seem to open, but when I reach my gamescreen everything is black. Everything is fine with the Samsung, I can see everything

Solved:

[GdxRuntimeException on Android: couldn't load shared library 'gdx' for target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698358/gdxruntimeexception-on-android-couldnt-load-shared-library-gdx-for-target?lq=1)

farskeptic's answer

Comment: Is there more to the log?  `ExceptionInInitializer` is usually only thrown if there is some other exception that fired during a constructor.

Comment: @P.T. could it be the first line of my log? the one with the GdxRuntimeException?

Comment: @P.T. Here's my log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p68r3yisg3chntg/log.txt

Comment: Maybe (the GdxRuntimeException often wraps other exceptions).  But there should be a backtrace that pin-points where the original exception is being thrown.

Comment: This: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gdx: findLibrary returned null

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698358/gdxruntimeexception-on-android-couldnt-load-shared-library-gdx-for-target