# Couldn't load shared library 'gdx' for target

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm having the same issue as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698358/gdxruntimeexception-on-android-couldnt-load-shared-library-gdx-for-target), but the answers there doesn't solve my problem.

I didn't create project by gdxsetup.jar, I just included gdx.jar and gdx-backend-android.jar. I added the libgdx.so to libs/x86, but it stills throws an exception. How should I solve this?

Logcat:

```
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788): Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'gdx' for target: Linux, 32-bit
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:114)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:34)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.<clinit>(AndroidApplication.java:62)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    ... 15 more
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gdx from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.example.gamr-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.example.gamr-1]: findLibrary returned null
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:355)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:525)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:110)
02-16 11:59:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14788):    ... 17 more
```

If it helps, I'm running 32-bit Linux.

Comment: Please include the full stack trace from logcat (this is on Android, right?).  It will (hopefully) include more details about the cause of the problem.

Comment: I added Logcat, but I don't know how to style it :(

Comment: just load the required shared library and that's all, what's the problem? `loadLibrary(String libname);` libname should come without `lib` and `.so`

Comment: You added the /x86 files, but did you add the /armeavi ones?

Comment: put     static {
        System.loadLibrary("gdx");
        System.loadLibrary("libgdx");
     } in but still doesn't work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out this is pretty simple :
add

```
static { System.loadLibrary("gdx");}
```

Comment: This answer seems like it will just cause confusion for other users (I'm not doubting your app works now, but its probably not the right way of fixing this).  This manual `loadLibrary` call should be redundant with what the LibGDX SharedLibraryLoader does.  Did you also add `armeabi/libgdx.so`to the APK? (Is your Android device ARM or x86?)

Comment: I thought so, quite redundant but I still need to load, I added already but still can't load.

Answer (score 10):

The problem I had was that for some reason `libgdx.so` was not copied to any of the `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a` or `x86` folders in the android project's `lib` folder.

Copying these over from the libgdx distribution worked for me.

Comment: where is the libgdx distribution?

Comment: This is so weird. Somehow the .so-files got deleted, although I didnt touch the project for months. Copying them back in helped. thx

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that I was trying to make my GDX app within a shared library (aka, not the thing that gets compiled into an APK), but hadn't finished setting up all the GDX-including stuff in my lib.

So I had:

```
MyProject
-->MyMainApp
-->-->build.gradle <-- no updates required, doesn't do anything with GDX
-->MySharedLibraryWhereMyGameEngineIs
-->-->build.gradle <-- this is where the problem was
```

In the shared lib's build.gradle, I hadn't included the `sourceSets` parameter.

Adding it fixed my problem.  GDX now starts up successfully.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    ... config stuff ...

    sourceSets {                       // this wasn't here before
        main {                         // this wasn't here before
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs'] // this wasn't here before
        }                              // this wasn't here before
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')// this wasn't here before
    }     

    ... a bunch of other config stuff ...
}
```

Comment: But instead of  instrumentTest they use androidTest currently

Answer (score 0):

I actually just faced the same problem after I uploaded by first update to my app ("October Bro"). While the first release has been run perfectly when installed from the Play Store, the update crashed right after launching. Checking Logcat, I exactly have been facing this issue.

The reason why my first release worked without a problem, but not the update was simple: because I only wanted to fix a minor bug, I checked out the project from GitHub, only ran the Desktop app once to verify the fix, and then created the signed AppBundle right away. It looks like I simply had to run the "android" run configuration at least once, before creating the AppBundle. Or to be more precise, the `build.grade` of the `android` module, which performs these tasks:

```
// android/build.gradle

...

// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives {
    doFirst {
        file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/x86/").mkdirs()

        configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
            def outputDir = null
            if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
            if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
            if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
            if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
            if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
            if(outputDir != null) {
                copy {
                    from zipTree(jar)
                    into outputDir
                    include "*.so"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that this `android/build.gradle` is executed anyways once I hit **Build > Build Bundle(s) / APK(s)**. But that does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by removing `armeabi` natives from the `copyAndroidNatives` task

```
// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives {
    doFirst {
        // file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/x86/").mkdirs()

        configurations.natives.copy().files.each { jar ->
            def outputDir = null
            if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
            if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
            // if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
            if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
            if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
            if(outputDir != null) {
                copy {
                    from zipTree(jar)
                    into outputDir
                    include "*.so"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```